# How to see file list in Rails from any folder, outer Rails.root - Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dir

I have rails application, I need see files in any folder. example
I have application on c:\rails_app and in controller write this code:

```
@files = Dir.glob("Z:/*")
```

and don't see file entire directory
in rails console work perfectly. 
I have question: 
How to see files from non rails directory? 
Thanks
--- after some answer
Problem not in use Dir class. Problem that Rails see only own root directory and i can`t change dir to other disk or folder in rails controller.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Dir#entries`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Dir.html#method-c-entries), [`Dir#glob`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob) or [`Dir#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Dir.html#method-c-5B-5D) to get a listing in any folder.

```
Dir.entries('/Users/ccashwell/.vim/')
=> [".",
 "..",
 ".git",
 ".gitignore",
 ".gitmodules",
 ".netrwhist",
 "ackrc",
 "after",
 "autoload",
 "bundle",
 "init",
 "LICENSE",
 "README.md",
 "snippets",
 "syntax",
 "vimrc"]

Dir.glob('/Users/ccashwell/.vim/*')
=> ["/Users/ccashwell/.vim/ackrc",
 "/Users/ccashwell/.vim/after",
 "/Users/ccashwell/.vim/autoload",
 "/Users/ccashwell/.vim/bundle",
 "/Users/ccashwell/.vim/init",
 "/Users/ccashwell/.vim/LICENSE",
 "/Users/ccashwell/.vim/README.md",
 "/Users/ccashwell/.vim/snippets",
 "/Users/ccashwell/.vim/syntax",
 "/Users/ccashwell/.vim/vimrc"]

Dir['/Users/ccashwell/.vim/*']
=> ["/Users/ccashwell/.vim/ackrc",
 "/Users/ccashwell/.vim/after",
 "/Users/ccashwell/.vim/autoload",
 "/Users/ccashwell/.vim/bundle",
 "/Users/ccashwell/.vim/init",
 "/Users/ccashwell/.vim/LICENSE",
 "/Users/ccashwell/.vim/README.md",
 "/Users/ccashwell/.vim/snippets",
 "/Users/ccashwell/.vim/syntax",
 "/Users/ccashwell/.vim/vimrc"]
```

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent of `ls` (list files) from the rails console is

```
Dir.entries(Dir.pwd)
```

e.g.

```
Dir.entries(Dir.pwd)

# Returns this:

=> [".", "..", ".DS_Store", "app", ".ruby-version", "test", "bin", "config", "config.ru", 
 "storage", "README.md", "Rakefile", "public", ".gitignore", "package.json", "lib", "db",
 "Gemfile", "log", "Gemfile.lock", "init.R", ".git", "tmp", "vendor"]
```

Comment: `Dir.ls` would be much more discoverable and convenient.

Answer (score 0):

I think what can be happening to you is that `\` [escapes next character](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob). Try:

```
@files = Dir.glob("Z:\\*")
```

or:

```
@files = Dir.glob("Z:/*")
```

Answer (score 0):

As *juanpastas* mentions, this might be an escape problem. The underlying problem, however, is that a path is not a string! A path is a path(object) and could best be treated as such:

```
path = File.join("Z:", "*")
puts path
@files = Dir.glob(path)
```

Or, shorthand:

```
@files = Dir.glob(File.join("Z:", "*"))
```

Additionally, Rails (and other apps) have wrapped this [Pathname](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) in e.g. `Rails.root`, use like so:

```
@files = Rails.root.join("lib") #=> Z:\path\to\rails\app\lib.
```